# Trunking cisco switch

Tags: networking

We have a an ISP router located in one building and a firewall on a different building in my company. We want all internet traffic to pass through the firewall. The ISP router interface has an ip address of 41.215.82.77 subnet mask of 255.255.255.252 and Firewall interface an ip address of 41.215.82.78 subnet mask of 255.255.255.252. In between the two buildings there are cisco 3750 switches. When Ethernet cable is connected directly from the router to the firewall by passing the switches, internet service becomes available. When the cables are connected to switches, and the ports on the switch configured to trunk ports, internet service becomes unavailable. How can I make the internet service available without connecting the cable directly from the router to the firewall? PS the cable was just borrowed for testing purposes and the lanlord does not want the cable to be used. Can someone give me advice me how I can configure the switches to allow internet traffic pass directly to the switches without compromising on security.

Answer (score 0):

Create a VLAN for the "outside" traffic. Ensure that the router and outside port of the firewall are connected to "untagged" interfaces in that VLAN and that no other ports are members of that VLAN.  Lastly, ensure that the new VLAN is getting trunked between the two switches properly.